# a question on upper bound for Bessel function $K_{2it}(x)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, bessel-functions, l-functions

Can we have $$K_{2it}(x)\sinh(t)\ll_{x} 1$$ for $1<x< (1+|t|)^3,$ where $K_{2it}(x)$ deotes the ordinary K-bessel function and $t>1$. This is true when $x\ge (1+|t|)^3$ from some references. Much obliged, if you can show me something or revelant literature.